# I want to output 20 numbers?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I have an array that has the size 20 values, but when I run my code it only outputs 3 values.How do I input 20 values into my array?

```
 public class LoopsMaybe
{
  public static void main(String [] args)
  {

    int[] lott = new int[20];
  for( int i=5; i<lott.length;i=i+7)
  {


      System.out.println(i);


      }

  }

 }
```

Output:
5
12
19

I want it to print out 5,12,19,26, 33, 40, 47.....and stop at the 20th number in the sequence

Comment: Are you trying to fill the array with numbers `5`, `12`, `19`, `26`, ... ?

Comment: Huh?!? You're not using array, and your loop starts at 5 with increment of 7, up to max 19, so you get 3 values. What did you expect?

Comment: As Andreas mentioned, your counter states this. (Add to 5, what ever 5 is aading by 7.  So since your array is 20 in length, it only loops 3 times. My example says, add to array of length 20, by 5 and increment at 7 20 times.

Comment: Are you trolling yourself, or have you been trolled?  It's a shame that you found this website before you learned the very basics of syntax and semantics if this post has any merit, Mila.  :(  You're never going to become a good programmer if you're not curious enough to attempt to change some of those values around and check for changes in output.

Comment: I also don't think people should down score a question, just because it seems stupid. Others are just learning still, and if copied the code, may not understand why. YES people should research and understand, but then help them explain why this is, not just down grade it.We are here to build comunity, not show who is better or worse, or to get points.

Comment: Please, can you first correct your logic in the code. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: I want it to print out  5,12,19,26, 33, 40, 47.....and stop at the 20th number in the sequence

Comment: @Mila Then why do you need the array?

Answer (score 2):

A very easy and concise way to get this done, for those interested in Java 8 niceties, is:

```
int seed = 5, inc = 7, many = 20;
IntStream is = IntStream.iterate(seed, n -> n + inc);
is.limit(many).forEach(x -> System.out.print(x + " "));
```

> Output: 5 12 19 26 33 40 47 54 61 68 75 82 89 96 103 110 117 124 131 138

Comment: I miss understood that question, and love this response. I had no idea to iterate that style.

Comment: @Casey, that happens to me all the time! Java 8 has a few gems well worth taking a look at.

Comment: I could do so, since it is similar to my language. I work with C#.

Answer (score 0):

If you must use the array then you need something else to perform the increment by 7. That way you are guaranteed 20 iterations.

```
public class LoopsMaybe
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {

        int[] lott = new int[20];
        int inc=5;
        for( int i=0; i<lott.length;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(inc);
            inc += 7;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class LoopsMaybe {

    public static void main(String [] args) {

        int[] lott = new int[20];
        int val = 5;
        for(int i=0; i<lott.length; i++) {
            lott[i] = val;
            System.out.println(val);
            val = val + 7;
        }
    }

}
```